# Is there a way to setup alerts for a failed DFS topology connection?

Tags: dfs, topology, alerting

I have a large DFS structure setup between multiple remote sites and multiple hub servers in a full mesh topology. Each remote site has its own namespace or namespaces and replication group. I have an automated PowerShell script that collects the Envrionment Health Report of all DFS servers on the network and alert me to backlogs in replication.

I noticed this morning that one particular site had a broken topology connection between itself and it's hub server. The error was the typical "There is a disconnected topology between servers in this replication group" or whatever the standard verbiage is in the DFS Management Console. This had been broken for some time. Our backup team only backs up from the hub, so the last backup file modify date on the backup files was around mid-2014. I had no way of knowing this until I stumbled across it.

Is there something I can run that can trigger an alert on the topology connections of a DFS setup? Whether it be a report or something that I can hook SolarWinds into to generate an alert on?

Comment: Do you have SCOM in your environment? SCOM has a lot of monitoring rules/alerts to choose from. Or you can right a script puts a time-stamped file in a replication group periodically, and check its existence on all partners. It shouldn't be too difficult at all.